Impact of Sandbox Refresh on Conga Product
I’m curious about the impact of refreshing a sandbox environment on the Conga product. Will refreshing the sandbox cause any issues with Conga's functionality, such as data loss or configuration problems? Are there any best practices to follow to ensure Conga continues to work smoothly after the sandbox refresh?
Thanks in advance!

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  You need to check with Conga support resources.
